# Can not get NodeMCU webserver to work

Tags: esp8266, arduino-ide, nodemcu, esplorer

So I have brought a NodeMCU and I am just trying to get a basic project to work over wifi. Well this project here:
 https://randomnerdtutorials.com/esp8266-web-server-with-arduino-ide

Now I have it all setup and ready to go I uploaded the code to the board and the serial told me Wifi Connected, ip address 192.168.1.12

I navigate to the ip address on either my phone or computer and they both tell me this site cant be reached.

I tried googling the answer to this issue on my own however all that comes up is "make sure the device is on the same network" and that's the only answer that I can find. All my devices are on the same ssid.

after a while of googling I tried flashing it with NODEMCU FIRMWARE PROGRAMER 
and it looked like it flashed successfully but it did not make any difference.

then I tried to see if I could use ESPlorer but everytime I try to connect it just keeps saying communication with mcu... and just hangs there.

Can someone please tell me whats going wrong. I've tried to look on the nodeMCU  website but there support page just redirects me to here stack overflow.

Thank you

Comment: "make sure the device is on the same network" means that your devices need to be on the same subnet 192.168.1.x (with netmask 255.255.255.0).

Comment: They are on the same subnet. The server is 192.168.1.12 and my phone is 192.168.1.13 and there's no way to check the device netmask as it is a nodeMCU

Comment: Ok, the problem is somewhere else then. You probably are using the correct port number?

Comment: Yes its on port 80

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I worked out that the problem was with the network router for some reason it was stopping my nodeMCU from being viewed on the network. I factory reset the router and evey thing then worked.